# Whats the Problem? Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'operator' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Its in Python. There isnt much to say about it, its not finished, but I must pass the error to finish. The error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'operator' referenced before assignment
its the line with: x = operator.add(zahl1, zahl2)

```
import operator 
def input1(a, b):
  zahl1 = a(input('Bitte geben sie die erste Zahl an'))
  op = input('''
welcher Operator soll benutzt werden?
Hier, einige Möglichkeiten:
+, -, *(mal), /(geteilt)''')
  zahl2 = b(input('Bitte geben sie die zweite Zahl an'))
  print('Das Ergebnis lautet: ', zahl1, )
  x = operator.add(zahl1, zahl2)
  xx = operator.sub(zahl1, zahl2)
  xxx = operator.truediv(zahl1, zahl2)
  xxxx = operator.mul(zahl1, zahl2)
  operator = {'+':x, '-':xx, '/':xxx, '*':xxxx}
  
 
zahl0  = str(input('''Wird eine Kommazahl benutzt? 
x für Nein, y für Die Erste Zahl, a für Beide Zahlen'''))
if zahl0 == 'x':
  type1 = 1
  type2 = 2
elif zahl0 == 'y':
  type1 = 1.2
  type2 = 1
else:
  type1 = 2.2
  type2 = 2.9

input1(type(type1), type(type2))
```

Comment: You're creating a local variable called `operator` here: `operator = {'+':x, '-':xx, '/':xxx, '*':xxxx}`. Don't do that. You don't want a local variable with the same name as the global variable `operator` (which is the operator module).

Comment: Thats the libary i cant do something diffrent

Comment: You can remove the line `operator = {'+':x, '-':xx, '/':xxx, '*':xxxx}` or call it something else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning a value to `operator`, but `operator` is an imported lib. Just change the `operator = {'+':x, '-':xx, '/':xxx, '*':xxxx}` assignment, use another variable, and it should work, so you can kept working on your algorithm

```
import operator

def input1(a, b):
    zahl1 = a(input('Bitte geben sie die erste Zahl an'))
    op = input('''
welcher Operator soll benutzt werden?
Hier, einige Möglichkeiten:
+, -, *(mal), /(geteilt)''')
    zahl2 = b(input('Bitte geben sie die zweite Zahl an'))
    print('Das Ergebnis lautet: ', zahl1, )
    x = operator.add(zahl1, zahl2)
    xx = operator.sub(zahl1, zahl2)
    xxx = operator.truediv(zahl1, zahl2)
    xxxx = operator.mul(zahl1, zahl2)
    result = {'+': x, '-': xx, '/': xxx, '*': xxxx}
    print(result)


zahl0 = str(input('''Wird eine Kommazahl benutzt? 
x für Nein, y für Die Erste Zahl, a für Beide Zahlen'''))
if zahl0 == 'x':
    type1 = 1
    type2 = 2
elif zahl0 == 'y':
    type1 = 1.2
    type2 = 1
else:
    type1 = 2.2
    type2 = 2.9

input1(type(type1), type(type2))
```